# ASP.NET MVC Response file should not download

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am generating a .cxml file on the server and pushing it to the browser based on certain queries. If I just link to a .cxml, it does what I expected and opens it in the respective application.

How can I generate a file and push it to the browser just like if it was linked to a file without it asking me to download it?

The link looks something like:

> http://localhost/MyController/GetFile?q=TheQueryStringParam

Thanks.

Comment: Somebody help me reword my header, as I'm not sure what keywords to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Response.Write(yourFileText) should do the trick